# Error deleting a section on UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I have 3 sections that are populated by an array of arrays. Each section has a header and a button that deletes the current section. When I tap the delete button I get the following Error:

**Error:**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of items in section 0.  The number of items contained in an existing section after the update (8) must be equal to the number of items contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of items inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of items moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).'

This is the code for the delete *function*

```
@IBAction func deleteSection(_ sender: UIButton) {

    // grab the tag representign the section
    let section = sender.tag
    // Update data model
    all.remove(at: section)

    // reload data to reflect section change
    // ignored due to delete sections


    photosCollection?.performBatchUpdates({
        self.photosCollection?.deleteSections(NSIndexSet(index: section) as IndexSet)
    }, completion: { (finished) in
        if finished {
            self.photosCollection?.reloadData()
        }
    })
 }
```

all is my array of arrays.

Comment: What's the point of calling `reloadData` after trying to call `deleteSections`?

Comment: I thought after deleting the section I have to reload the data because an array is deleted within the array of arrays called **all**. Each array inside  **all** populates a section.

Comment: You only call one or the other depending on the effect you want. And if you choose to stick with `deleteSections` you need to delete the same section you removed from your `all` array.

Comment: If I just call either I still get the same error.

Comment: Just calling `reloadData` will not give you that error. You can only get that error using `delete|insert|move|reloadSections` or the `Items` variants.

Comment: Oh okay so I got a new error saying: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Invalid update: invalid number of sections.  The number of sections contained in the collection view after the update (2) must be equal to the number of sections contained in the collection view before the update (2), plus or minus the number of sections inserted or deleted (0 inserted, 1 deleted).'

Comment: Just using the reload. So what could be the issue that is giving me this new error?

Comment: Oh never mind I got it fixed thanks